# Using exec() for automated testing of functions

Tags: python, testing, exec, eval

I want to create a testing Framework for some of my python functions (although this approach might work for any other language)

My idea is to create a file where I'll have:

- The name of function to be tested
- The input parameters for this function
- The expected output

My file will look like:

```
# Test 1: Description of the test    # foo test1
Function: foo
Input: param1, param2, param3
Output: out1, out2

# Test 2: Description of the test    # foo test2
Function: foo
Input: param1, param2, param3
Output: out1, out2

# Test 3: Description of the test    # bar test1
Function: bar
Input: param1, param2, param3, param4
Output: out1, out2, out3
```

I can then read this file and start executing the tests.

My initial idea was to first build the command in a string:

```
command = function + '(' + ''.join(inputs) + ')'
```

and then using `exec()` to execute each of the commands

```
exec(command)
```

However I'm guessing if this is a good idea or there are better ideas to do that.

I say that because exec and eval are considered bad practices to be avoided when possible.

So my question is: Is my approach OK or there is an easy other way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Rather than writing your own test framework have you considered using [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) ?

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case you described I suggest using `getattr`. Suppose the functions you want to test are located in a module called `functions`. Your testing function would look like:

```
def test(func_name, args, out):
    func = getattr(functions, func_name)
    # `args` is a tuple for example.
    assert func(*args) == out, "Test routine failed"
```

You can extract the function name, the arguments and the output from your configuration file.

When it comes to testing in general I recommend using [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). It might seem complicated at first glance but it has a very nice documentation and for larger projects it is definitely worth the effort. You could wrap the test procedure in a `unittest.TestCase` as follows:

```
FunctionTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, func_name, args, out):
        self.func = getattr(functions, func_name)
        self.args = args
        self.out = out
    def test_func(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.func(*self.args), self.out)
```